# texts_to_sequences() missing 1 required positional argument: 'texts'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

i have a array of comments with shape ((8084,)) (UTF-8) when i ran this cod i got error

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
X = Tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(data['comment_text'].values)
```

the error is 
**TypeError: texts_to_sequences() missing 1 required positional argument: 'texts'**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`texts_to_sequence` is not a class method, that's not the way to call it. Check out [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer#fit_on_texts) for an example.

You should first create a Tokenizer object and fit it, then you can call `texts_to_sequence`.

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
texts = data['comment_text'].values
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(texts)
X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(texts)
```